# AJAX loading and progressbar incompatible?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to load a page (call it second page) from a link in a jquery mobile page (call it first page) using AJAX (by default). The second page include a progressbar (jquery-ui). When I click on the link in first page, the the spinning wheel rotate continuously and the second page never load. Something I should know? I've looked many different post but found nothing that answer my question...

Here's the first page code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="first_page" data-title="MediaManager">
            <a href="second_page.php">Espace disque</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the second page code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="progressbar"></div>
        <script>
                $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({max: 10 });
                $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({value: 3 });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are missing some code.   You are only showing some code for the progress bar but we would also need to see the ajax code.  In addition what have you tried in your efforts to resolve the issue?

Comment: This code work perfectly well if I'm accessing the URL of second page directly in my browser. Jquery-mobile is taking care of the AJAX code for me, I'm only using an <A> tag in my first page. I can disable AJAX with _data-ajax="false"_ and the page load correctly but I need it to be loaded with AJAX so it's not an option.

Comment: So wheres you first page then. Obviously that's the page that has the problem not the one you posted.

Comment: I've edited the question with the code.

Comment: Add jquery-ui style and script tags inside page div. you're probably getting an error emitted from `.progressbar()`. JQM loads page div only and neglects others tags, so libraries in head aren't loaded.

Comment: I've just tried it and it doesn't change anything in AJAX and continue to work fine accessing page directly.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you need to wrap progress bar code in any of pagecontainer events. It depends on when you want to show it.

Comment: Could you please give me an exemple? I'm quite a newbie with JQuery in general. Thank you!

Comment: Check this link for detailed JQM page events http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/

Comment: Thank you Omar. I understant that your trying to teach me to fish, not give me a fish but this article is far beyond my understanding of jquery. I'm trying to use this as a personal project and I would really appreciate if you could shwo me with my code how to make it work. I really appreciate your help by the way! :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60195/discussion-between-omar-and-morpheus65535).

Answer (score 0):

[Omar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1771795/omar) helped me to solve my problem.

JQM doesn't use  when calling with AJAX so I have to include jquery-ui in . I've removed jquery-core that was already loaded in DOM from first page. Finally, I've have to assign my jquery script in a pagecontainer event.

Here's the code that work in my second page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="disk-space" data-title="Espace disque">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

            <div id="progressbar"></div>
            <script>
                $(document).on("pagecontainershow", function () {
                    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({max: 10 });
                    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({value: 3 });
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you Omar! :-)